# Need to migragte assemblies from SQL Server 2016 to SQL Server-2019 with TDE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, assemblies, sql-server-2019

A former colleague created some assemblies in SQL Server 2008 and we could migrate them easily to SQLServer 2016. I was able to do this myself so far but with SQL_Server 2019 policies have changed and assemblies need to be prepared and altered in advance before being imported.

With this major changes I am not able anymore to migrate the assemblies and need assistance.

I still have the sources from the assemblies and have visual studio code installed. But this is it

In total we are talking about 4 assemblies. I hope, if we can migrate at least one script, I can do the others on my own.

So far it was possible to just:

- right click on the assembly in SQL-Server -> Script assembly as -> create in new window
- Alter Database
- press <kbd>F5</kbd>

Comment: Can you explain how TDE (Transparent Data Encryption) is involved in the problem?

Comment: And I don't know whether the encryption of the database has an effect or not. 

I thought it may affect importing assemblies as assemblies need to be signed / encrypted in advance to be imported and that propably same keys or related keys should be used to interact with each other, but  I may be wrong. 

As I stated previously I am not that deep in that topic. 

sry

Comment: Can anyone push me in the right direction? 

What  would happen if I try the following:
Use an SQL-Server-2016 instance (similar to the current production environment) 
- Import the assemblies currently working
- upgrade to SQL-Server 2019
- Encrypt the SQL-Server 2019 

Will the assemblies still work as these are beeing internally modified by the upgrade to still work or will i get the same error, that assemblies can not be used anymore. ? 

My hope is, that already working assemblies are passed through and will still work, and only importing new one may require "pre-working" Thx